# selenium UnhandledalertException on firefox not executing Webdriver Classes

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

After Autoit script completes login me through windows authenticate my selenium stops working and not executing any command on browser (Firefox)

System

Version: 19.0
Platform:Windows 7
Firefox: 56.0 (64 bit)
Selenium: 3.6.0
Testcase

I want to get title of my webpage but unbale to print it as browser not reading any .driver class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/aamir.fatimi/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64/geckodriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://dbu-export-09/en/Pages/default.aspx");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\aamir.fatimi\\Desktop\\AutoIT\\Autoit.exe");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
String get_Title = driver.getTitle();

System.out.println("Title is" + get_Title);
driver.quit();
```

Comment: Is there any exception shown or it just hangs?

Comment: Try using Thread.sleep() function or try in debug mode.

Comment: @AlexeyR. i have mentioned stack trace not get hanged it just open my webpage after authentication and then dont execute any command

Comment: @AlexeyR. one more thing is happening when i do the same thing in chrome when selenium click my mentioned element then it start reloading the webpage which makes my script to get failed.

Comment: "when selenium click my mentioned element". As I can see from your script Selenium does not click any element. Only AutoIt does. Selenium just loads the page and then attempts to get the page title.

Comment: I have the same issue, I submitted this to geckodriver, https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/977.

Comment: @smit9234 yes i have been seriously banging my head since last week couldn't resolve this issue

Answer (score -1):

**EDITED:**

You can try to wait for alert to be absent in this way:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
    .until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()));
```

right after your Autoit script execution to make sure that WebDriver get's title when Autoit actually is finished.
Assuming of course your Autoit script doesn't leave any alerts hanging, in which case you can simply try:

```
//Snippet from answer of smit9234 - not tested
try {
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.sendKeys(username + Keys.TAB.toString() + password);
    alert.accept();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

again, right after (or probably even instead, if the script is supposed to close the alert and just works incorrectly/inconsistently) the script. Or modify Autoit to close alert, and go with option 1.

Comment: How ho you know the alert is windows alert if this info was not provided? And how in this case  my suggestion to close alert with Autoit doesn't help? Please reconsider your downvote.

Comment: Sorry, but what does this have to do with anything? Have you read my response?

Comment: Kudin, edit your answer and I will upvote you.  Your answer is correct.

Comment: Edited with your snippet

Answer (score -2):

Expanding on the Kudin's Answer above:

1. Remove the AutoIT script
2. Add the following in place of it

> ```
> try {
>     Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
>     alert.sendKeys(yourusername + Keys.TAB.toString()+yourpassword);
>     alert.accept();
> } catch (Exception e) {
>     e.printStackTrace();
> }
> ```